# Rearrange apps with Apple Configurator?

Tags: iphone, catalina

I'm using catalina and want to rearrange my app icons on my phone. I tried using Apple configurator program but can't seem to get it to work. After rearranging the icons, I hit "Apply" and the icons on the phone don't change.